# Is the Truststore/Keychain writable for the Chrome process?

Tags: macos, security, google-chrome, permission, keychain

While browsing a TLS-protected website in Chrome (89.0.4389.114), the button on the left side of the address bar opens a dropdown menu. Pressing on "Certificate" opens a (system-) dialog containing interactions for the TLS-Certificate for that Host:

[image]

I used that dialog to "Always Trust" a self-signed root certificate. It **seems like** this action does not trigger anything. Apparently the certificate was not added to the Keychain.

I do know that a (root-) certificate may be imported + trusted by copying it on the local filesystem, importing it into the Keychain and setting the trust level to "Always Trust".

I decided that i don't actually want to trust that CA, so i want to make sure that the certificate was not imported in any store!

Does anyone know what this dialog is doing / what actions are triggered when "Always Trust" is selected?

I tried to find logs for that action, but i'm new to Mac OS and was not able to find anything...

EDIT: Does Chrome on Mac OS maintain a separate trust store (For exceptions like the above mentioned)?